# How to format a string with a localized string?

Tags: string, xaml, binding, formatting, windows-phone-8

I want to bind a value and format it with a localized string. Something like that :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Age, StringFormat='\{0\} {Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Global_AgeSuffix, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}'}" />
```

Output :

- 30 ans   if french culture
- 30 years if other culture

Is it possible ?

Regards,

Flo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't format bound text this way on Windows Phone.

There are two alternatives.

1. Add another property to the bound object which has the formatting already applied
2. Apply the formatting with a converter.